# Create column with a certain condition in R

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, lapply, create-table

I have this data.

```
OPENING CLOSE 
2007     2008   
2009     2010    
2004      NA
```

and I would like to make this column

```
OPENING CLOSE Y2004 Y2005 Y2006 Y2007 Y2008 Y2009 Y2010
2007     2008                     1     1
2005     2008         1     1     1     1                                   
2004      NA    1     1     1     1     1     1     1
```

It is possible to create this column step by step with if function, while I'd like to make loop or lapply function.

Additionally, I want to make this column(S~) using a certain condition.

If a column (Y2007) is 1 and the column 3 years ago is 1 (Y2005), 
 The new column (S2007) is 1 and otherwise 0.

```
OPENING CLOSE Y2004 Y2005 Y2006 Y2007 Y2008 Y2009 Y2010 | S2007 S2008 S2009
2007     2008                     1     1               |   0     0     0
2005     2008         1     1     1     1               |   1     1     0
2004      NA    1     1     1     1     1     1     1   |   1     1     1
```

How do I make the script in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution from the `tidyverse`. `dt3` is the first desired output, while `dt5` is the second desired output. There is no need to use `loops` here.

```
# Create example data frame
dt <- read.table(text = "OPENING CLOSE 
2007     2008   
                 2005     2008    
                 2004      NA   ",
                 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Load package
library(tidyverse)

dt2 <- dt %>%
  mutate(ID = 1:n(), EndYear = ifelse(is.na(CLOSE), 2010, CLOSE)) %>%
  # Create year range list
  mutate(YearRange = map2(OPENING, EndYear, `:`)) %>%
  # Unnest the list column
  unnest() %>%
  mutate(YearRange = paste0("Y", YearRange)) %>%
  mutate(Value = 1) %>%
  # Spread based on YearRange and Value
  spread(YearRange, Value)

# Desired output 1  
dt3 <- dt2 %>%  
  arrange(ID) %>%
  select(-ID, -EndYear)

dt4 <- dt2 %>%
  gather(YearRange, Value, Y2004:Y2010) %>%
  arrange(ID) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  # Set the lag year here, using 3 years ago as an example
  mutate(Value2 = lag(Value, 2)) %>%
  # Evaluate the condition bewteen one year and 3 years ago
  mutate(Value3 = ifelse(Value %in% 1 & Value2 %in% 1, 1, 0)) %>%
  mutate(YearRange = sub("Y", "S", YearRange)) %>%
  select(ID, YearRange, Value3) %>%
  # Filter for S2007 o S2009
  filter(YearRange %in% paste0("S", 2007:2009)) %>%
  spread(YearRange, Value3)

# Desired output 2
dt5 <- dt2 %>%
  left_join(dt4, by = "ID") %>%
  arrange(ID) %>%
  select(-ID, -EndYear)
```

Comment: This is one of the great answers for me since I have seen!! thanks. Ah! I would like to set the additional filter below the code (filter(YearRange %in%~)). I want to do subset Y2007~Y2009 so that I wrote the code below that code but it doses not work. How do I revise the code to use two ways filtering?

Answer (score 0):

Base R version:

```
rng <- range(unlist(dat), na.rm=TRUE)
rng <- rng[1]:rng[2]

dat[paste0("Y",rng)] <- t(mapply(
  function(op,cl,rn) rn >= op & (rn <= cl | is.na(cl)),
  dat[["OPENING"]],
  dat[["CLOSE"]],
  list(rng)
))

#  OPENING CLOSE Y2004 Y2005 Y2006 Y2007 Y2008 Y2009 Y2010
#1    2007  2008 FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
#2    2009  2010 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
#3    2004    NA  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```